# Making fetch() work in both browser and node

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js

I have a small typescript plugin that runs in the browser, which uses `fetch`, e.g. `fetch(url)`.

To test the plugin using mocha, mocha runs in a node environment and because of this, `fetch` isn't implemented.

It can be made to work in node using:

```
declare const require: any
fetch = require('cross-fetch');
fetch(url)
```

However, the `require` statement raises an ugly error when running in the browser.

Ideally I'd like to have something like:

```
if(typeof fetch !== 'undefined'){ const fetch = require('cross-fetch'); }
fetch(url)
```

However, this obviously scopes fetch to the if statement and it can't be used globally. If I try

```
if(typeof fetch !== 'undefined'){ fetch = require('cross-fetch'); }
```

Then typescript complains that `fetch` is already defined as a function (typescript is basing this on the browser environment). So it won't compile.

Is there a way to either 1.) tell typescript that `fetch` might NOT be defined even though it thinks that it is, or 2.) to enable `fetch` globally some other way

---

Meta-question: how are other people testing their browser-based javascript? Surely there's an easier way than making the javascript work in a node environment?

Comment: You're going to need to put fetch in the global object in initialization code somewhere. This answer has a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485826/getting-referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined-when-running-react-native-tests-in

Comment: `const xfetch = typeof fetch !== 'undefined' ? fetch : require('cross-fetch');`

Comment: That's a very clean way epascarello, nice.